# class already defined in null

Tags: java, inheritance

When I try inheritance an error comes up "CheckingAccount is already defined in null".   What does this mean and how can I fix this?
This is the code that I have:

```
public class BankAccount 
{
    double balance;

    public void Bankaccount() {
        balance = 0;
    }

    public BankAccount(double initialBalance) {
        initialBalance = balance;
    }

    public void deposite(double amount) {
        balance = balance + amount;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }

    public double getBalance(double balance) {
        return balance;
    }

    public void transfer(double amount, double bankAccountOther) {
        balance = balance - amount;

    }
}

public class CheckingAccount 
{
    public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me out here, I really don't understand what it means

Comment: Why are you trying to declare 2 classes `CheckingAccount`, wrongly, one within the other?

Comment: Formatting your source generally makes things stand out and easier to spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same class defined inside itself, this is the problem:

```
public class CheckingAccount {
    public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount{
    }
}
```

The inner class should be named differently. Or maybe you intended the outer class to extend `BankAccount`? it's not clear what you were trying to implement, but maybe this is what you were aiming for:

```
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount{
}
```

Comment: @user2174244 yep, you'll have to write a new constructor for receiving the `double initialBalance` parameter, but inside you can call the constructor in the superclass, like this: `super(initialBalance)`

Answer (score 1):

The answer was already successfully given plenty of times, but I would add an unrelated remark, concerning this piece of code:

```
//constructor
    public void Bankaccount()
    {
    balance = 0;
    }
```

This is not a constructor. If you want it to be a constructor, you must delete `void`

Answer (score 0):

You should write only -

```
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount{

    }
```

and not

```
public class CheckingAccount {
    public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount{

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below :

```
public class CheckingAccount {
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount{

    }
}
```

By this :

```
 public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount{

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is most likely right here:

```
public class CheckingAccount {
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount{

    }
}
```

You're defining a CheckingAccount class within an already existent CheckingAccount class. I don't think you can hide an enclosed type.

Answer (score 0):

```
1   class CheckingAccount {
2   public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {
3
4        }
5   }
```

remove 1st and 5 line above and add no-argument constructor in Super class

Answer (score 0):

Another side note that isn't really an answer:

```
public BankAccount(double initialBalance) {
        initialBalance = balance;
    }
```

should be

```
public BankAccount(double initialBalance) {
        balance = initialBalance;
    }
```

as the former accomplishes nothing.